# Replace variable text after fixed text

Tags: python

So I have a .txt file that looks similar to this:

```
Patient Name         : John Don, 9989
Patient ID           : 9989
Comment              : Summation
Date                 : 09.08.2017
Exported by          : Denver
Type                 : DVH
Description          : Some random text
```

I also have another list with names that I want to use instead.

So basically, I have several of these .txt files in different folders named by the same names as I would have in my list, fx:

```
name_list = ["1", "1_NEW", "2", "3", "3_RE"]
```

The thing I would like to do is to change the value of the `Patient name` and `Patient ID` to whatever is in the list.

So for example, for the for the first element in the list it opens the folder with the same name, and then open the .txt file in that folder (same name always), read the .txt file, and change the values AFTER the `Patient name` and `Patient ID` to the value of the list. So for the first one I would end up with:

```
Patient Name         : 1
Patient ID           : 1
Comment              : Summation
Date                 : 09.08.2017
Exported by          : Denver
Type                 : DVH
Description          : Some random text
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Are the file names like the list? i.e. - `"1", "1_NEW", "2", "3", "3_RE"`? and are they all in the same parent directory?

Comment: I have a directory filled with +1000 folders with different names. In all of these folders there are a .txt file (like the one above) that has the same name. And all these folder names I have in a list like shown. And the list value for each folder is what I want to change the "Patient Name" and "Patient ID" into.

Comment: Of course it can be done, but may I ask how you ended up with this structure in the first place? It would be more efficient putting them in a json, csv or if very large a database?

Comment: Well, besides that one thing in the top, where I want to change the names, there are also approximately 1.3 mio. line of data for EACH file. And the program that extracted the data, well, that did it as individual .txt files for each case/patient. So maybe not optimal, but that was the way things turned out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair enough, here is a code example you could use:

> Be warned though as this could overwrite files (try with one file)

```
for file in ["1"]:

    # Read file
    with open("{0}/{0}.txt".format(file)) as f:
        filecontent = [i.strip("\n") for i in f.readlines()]    

    # Update first and second row
    filecontent[0] = filecontent[0].split(":")[0] + ": {}".format(file)
    filecontent[1] = filecontent[1].split(":")[0] + ": {}".format(file)

    # Ovewrite old file and write
    with open("{0}/{0}.txt".format(file), "w") as f:
        string = '\n'.join(filecontent)
        f.write(string)
        # print(string)
```

Comment: Wow, that really did the trick. And yes, it did overwrite. But that is totally fine. Thank you so much.